# Trying to do an OR test with JSTL inside my jsp template

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

i have the following code from my JSP which doesn't quite work:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
<c:set var="requestURI" value="${pageContext.request.requestURI}" />
<c:set var="isPeople" value="${fn:contains(requestURI, '/People/')}" />
<c:set var="isJobs"   value="${fn:contains(requestURI, '/Jobs/') || fn:endsWith(requestURI,contextPath+'/')}" />
```

Basically, isPeople is working fine - it checks to see if the user is on any of my pages that have '/People/' in the url, and uses that later on down to show the appropriate submenu.

Now i wand the isJobs to be true if they are at either '/Jobs/*' or the application root, but my simple || doesn't compile, it gives me this error:

```
An exception occurred processing JSP page /sitemesh/main.jsp at line 7
```

Please help, thanks!

Comment: I think the offending part is the string concatenation: contextPath+'/'

Comment: Isn't the `fn:contains` a bit weak? What about `/People/Jobs/`? Don't you want `fn:startsWith`? Endusers can often append paths to end of URL without affecting the webapp in any way.

Comment: Not really worried about security in this particular app, but that's a good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, string concatenation doesn't work that way in EL.

The following should work:

```
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/" />
<c:set var="requestURI" value="${pageContext.request.requestURI}" />
<c:set var="isPeople" value="${fn:contains(requestURI, '/People/')}" />
<c:set var="isJobs"   value="${fn:contains(requestURI, '/Jobs/') || fn:endsWith(requestURI, contextPath)}" />
```

Note that I moved the trailing slash from the `fn:endsWith` to the `<c:set value>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot: this works, however it may affect further down in my code where the 'contextPath' variable gets used, which ideally i'd like to avoid.